# Retrieve data from postgresql in fastest way using python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I have the following code:

```
list1=[]
flatList_val=['user1','user2','user3','user4',......]
for val in flatList_val:
    #count=flatList.count(val)
    query="select count(title) as count from Data where authors like '%"+val+"%'"
    luk=getValues("",query)
    list1.append({"id":val,"size":(luk['count'].values[0])*20})
```

I have many elements in flatlist.How could I retrieve the data in fastest way from POSTgresql db?
Note:The getvalues function is just python code using psycog2 for data retrieval.
I am basically looking for a query with fastest execution

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using pandas dataframe actually.Please find the solution below:
Instead of querying each time,I queried all the information and stored in dataframe

```
    query="select authors from Data"
    luk=getValues("",query)
    
            for val in flatList_val:
                
                count=luk.authors.str.count(val).sum()
                list1.append({"id":val,"size":count*30})
```